# Get values from input in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, input

I started writing an associative array like this:

`$array01 = array("George" => "USA", "Mario => "Italy", "Raj" => "India");`

Then I echo it

`foreach($array01 as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Name=" . $x . ", Country=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}`

Now I would like to create a function that takes as input a name written by the user and that returns the corresponding value. For example if the user enters "George", the output will be "USA" (maybe with a textbox for input?). I tried a lot of methods but nothing worked. 
Here is my attempt:

```
echo("Who are you looking for?");

$country = $_POST[$x];
{
foreach( $country as $key => $x_value )
    echo $array01[$x];
}
```

Comment: "I tried a lot of methods but nothing worked." can't really help us to debug your code. Can you please include your best attempt and describe which problem you ran into?

Comment: You're missing a form and how you get the input from the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function like

```
function printCountry($name) {
   $array01 = array("George" => "USA", "Mario" => "Italy", "Raj" => "India");
   return $array01[$name];
}
```

then, call the function like

```
printCountry($_POST['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a mere addition, you could check if the values exists in the array using for example [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) before getting the value by index.

You could also add a check for getting `$country` from the POST array.

```
/**
 * @param $name
 * @return string|null
 */
function printCountry($name) {
    $array01 = array("George" => "USA", "Mario" => "Italy", "Raj" => "India");
    return array_key_exists($name, $array01) ? $array01[$name] : null;
}
```